# Close button doesn't work after pop-up is opened and closed from same page (only Edge)

Tags: javascript, jquery-events

I have page with buttons (href='#' with attached onclick event) 'Print' and 'Close'.
When Print is clicked a new windows pop-up with standard Windows 10 print option page. Then you click 'Cancel' or just close the Print pop-up page and after that the 'Close button' doesn't work anymore.

If you don't click 'Print' the 'Close' is working.
This is happening only on Edge.

I have read almost everything I could find in stackoverflow and not only for problems with window.close() or similar. I have tried multiply other solutions and none of them worked, some of them are:

```
href="#" onclick="(function(e){e.preventDefault(); window.close()})(event)"

event.view.close();

event.view.top.close();

window.open('','_self').close();

var ww = window.open(window.location, '_self'); 
ww.close();
```

I just don't understand what is wrong and why this doesn't work.
I simply attach onclick function in my JavaScript which executes some of the above listed code options and in the end I have:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

so it won't execute the default behavior of href="#".

Is there someone who can help with this, because I'm out of solutions already?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: After more google search I found the following [thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/edge-browser-windowclose-not-working-if-print-is/737abfbf-d9af-4469-8d67-6ec9288d420f) which is exactly the same issue I'm experiencing.

A few minutes later I found and ['window.close() is not working after print cancel'](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7125650/).

I hope they will release the version soon, so the fix can be applied.